# numerical solution of characteristic equation for hybrid modes in fiber

Tags: equation-solving

I have solved Maxwell's equations in optical fiber and now I want to solve the final equation numerically. This equation consists of Bessel function of the first and second kind and their derivatives. I used NDsole, NSOlve, Findroot,... but none of them give me answer. can you please help me. thank you
    `NSolve[{(BesselJ[m, u]/(u*(1/2*(J[m - 1, u] - J[m + 1, u]))) + 
        BesselK[m, w]/(
        w*((-1/2)*(BesselK[m - 1, w] - BesselK[m + 1, w]))))*(BesselJ[
         m, u]/(u*(1/2*(J[m - 1, u] - J[m + 1, u]))) + ((n1/
           n2)^2*(BesselK[m, w]/(
           w*((-1/2)*(BesselK[m - 1, w] - 
                BesselK[m + 1, w])))))) - (m^2*(1/u^2 + 1/w^2)*(1/
         u^2 + ((n1/n2)^2*1/w^2))) == 0, u^2 + w^2 == V^2}, {u, w}]]`
This is the code I used. and the only variables are u and w

Comment: Can you provide us with the code you are using for doing so (even if it is not working)?

Comment: Please edit the question instead of adding comments. Make the question clear and self contained. In the edit mode, there is a help bulb (top right corner) which will guide you though code formatting and similar issues.

Comment: Ok Kuba. thank you

Comment: You say " the only variables are u and w", but what about the lot of paramters in the equation? What values do they have?  How do you think to get a numerical solution, if  `NSolve` does not know them?

Comment: I have the value for other parameters and after setting these values NSolve does not give the answer